# Use of Dash or Hyphen in Telephone Numbers

Tags: pronunciation

If reading out a telephone number

e.g. 123-456789

Denwa bangō wa ichi ni san - yon go roku nana hachi kyū desu

What is the dash / hyphen called? Is it spoken? If so how is it pronounced or how do you write it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can either pause at a dash or read it as の.

As you can see in [this page](http://www.tv-asahi.co.jp/announcer/nihongo/labo/004/body.html), where two professional announcers are discussing how to correctly read/pronounce numbers, it is also correct to read a phone number 03-1230-4050 as 「れいさん**の**　いちにさんれい**の**　よんれいごれい」.

Also [in this TV commercial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TPWziwoOqAw&feature=youtu.be&t=102) they read 0120-999-666 as 「ぜろいちに(い)ぜろ　きゅうきゅうきゅう**の**　ろくろくろく」, and [in this TV commercial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQIGm-hWPfY&feature=youtu.be&t=84) 0120-666-666 as 「ぜろいちに(い)ぜろ**の**　ろくろくろく**の**　ろくろくろく」.

So, for example 0123-456-7890 can be read:

> 「れいいちに(い)さん <sub>(pause)</sub> よんご(お)ろく <sub>(pause)</sub> ななはちきゅうれい」-- pausing at each dash
>   「れいいちに(い)さん <sub>(pause)</sub> よんご(お)ろく**の** ななはちきゅうれい」-- using a pause and の
>   「れいいちに(い)さん**の** よんご(お)ろく**の** ななはちきゅうれい」-- using の

Actually in recent years it has become much more common to read the number "0" as 「ぜろ」 than as 「れい」 (at least in real life), as in:

> 「ぜろいちに(い)さん <sub>(pause)</sub> よんご(お)ろく <sub>(pause)</sub> ななはちきゅうぜろ」
>   「ぜろいちに(い)さん <sub>(pause)</sub> よんご(お)ろく**の** ななはちきゅうぜろ」
>   「ぜろいちに(い)さん**の** よんご(お)ろく**の** ななはちきゅうぜろ」

Answer (score 2):

### Examples

Tokyo: 03-1234-5678
Yokohama: 045-123-4567
Docomo: 090-1234-5678

As you know, the first part is used to distinguish the regions you live in or the carrier company of cell phone.  The latter two parts are phone numbers for each subscriber. The dash or hyphen is used for the convenience to memorizing or transcribing them. When you read them, you are supposed to read them with a short pause at the dashes.

---

### EDIT

### 【上級編｛じょうきゅうへん｝】

少｛すこ｝し長｛なが｝いですが日本語の勉強だと思って時間｛じかん｝があったらお読｛よ｝みください。

ǝʇɐןoɔoɥƆの答えの中に、アナウンサーが電話｛でんわ｝番号｛ばんごう｝の「–」をどう読｛よ｝むかの引用｛いんよう｝がありましたが、気｛き｝になりましたので、EDITします。引用によると「–」をすべて「の」と読むのが正解｛せいかい｝とあります。

私の住｛す｝んでいる横浜｛よこはま｝を例｛れい｝に、回答｛かいとう｝のために作為的{さくいてき}に作｛つく｝った電話番号で説明｛せつめい｝します。

> 045–123–4567

アナウンサーが正解だとする「045 **の** 123–4567」とは私は言いません。後半｛こうはん｝は「123 **の** 4567」あるいは「123 **pause** 4567」です。なぜ、「045 **の**」と言わないのでしょうか。

外国｛がいこく｝でもそうでしょうが、日本では携帯｛けいたい｝電話が登場｛とうじょう｝するまでは、今もそうですが、電話番号は、「市外｛しがい｝局番｛きょくばん｝045」と「市内局番 123」と「加入者｛かにゅうしゃ｝番号 4567」いう３つの番号[体系]｛たいけい｝で運用｛うんよう｝されてきました。「市内局番」と「加入者番号」とは厳密｛げんみつ｝には全く違う番号ですが、私たち市民｛しみん｝には差｛さ｝が分｛わ｝かりませんので、ここの説明｛せつめい｝では「市内番号」という造語｛ぞうご｝で一括｛いっかつ｝して説明します。ここでの説明では「123–4567」全体で「市内番号」です。「市外局番」とはエリアコード（*area code* 厳密には0を除いた45）のようなものです。厳密ではありませんが、概｛おおむ｝ね行政｛ぎょうせい｝の「市｛し｝ *city*」の単位｛たんい｝と同じ区域｛くいき｝を同一エリアコードに割｛わ｝り当｛あ｝てておりますので、「市内」「市外」という用語｛ようご｝が使われております。細｛こま｝かなことは抜｛ぬ｝きにしますと、携帯電話が登場｛とうじょう｝する前は、日本国内の電話は日本[電信電話]{でんしんでんわ}[公社]{こうしゃ}（その後ＮＴＴ＝日本電信電話株式会社）が独占的｛どくせんてき｝に営業｛えいぎょう｝しておりました。日本電信電話公社がエリアコード毎｛ごと｝に電話[交換機]｛こうかんき｝をもった電話[交換局]｛こうかんきょく｝を設置{せっち}し、エリア内外｛ないがい｝の加入｛かにゅう｝電話の接続｛せつぞく｝・交換｛こうかん｝をしておりました。交換局ごとに割り当てられた番号が「市外局番」になります。同一のエリアコード（市外局番）を持った人、大｛おお｝まかに言うと同じ市内に住んでいる人同士｛どうし｝の電話は「市内番号」だけで行われます。当然、市外局番が違｛ちが｝う人同士が（エリアをまたいで）電話するときには、「市外局番 045」が必要｛ひつよう｝になり「045–123–4567」とダイヤル（懐｛なつ｝かしい言葉｛ことば｝ですね）します。

さて、自分｛じぶん｝の電話番号を他人｛たにん｝に伝｛つた｝えるときはどうするかです。
相手｛あいて｝も自分も同じエリアに住｛す｝んでいるときには、「市外局番」を伝える必要はありません。単｛たん｝に「市内番号」である「123–4567」を伝えます。その発音｛はつおん｝は、「いちにいさん の しいごおろく」か「いちにいさん pause しいごおろく」です。2,4,5は１音節｛おんせつ｝ですので聞｛き｝きやすいように母音｛ぼいん｝を伸｛の｝ばして「にい,しい,ごお」のように発音します。相手が自分と同じエリアの人かどうかわからないときと、明｛あき｝らかにエリアが違う人には「市外局番」を含｛ふく｝めて電話番号を伝えます。そのとき、突然｛とつぜん｝言うと市外局番から言ったのか市内番号だけを言ったのかが分かりづらいので、一般｛いっぱん｝に次｛つぎ｝のように言っておりました。「横浜｛よこはま｝045 pause 123–4567」。前半｛ぜんはん｝は、「よこはまぜろよんごお pause」です。後半｛こうはん｝の「123–4567」の伝え方は、前に述べた「市内番号」だけを伝える方法｛ほうほう｝と同｛おな｝じです。「市外局番」は、横浜[以外]｛いがい｝では、「東京｛とうきょう｝03」「大阪｛おおさか｝06」「京都｛きょうと｝075」などです。

ここで携帯電話の登場｛とうじょう｝です。携帯電話は今までの家庭｛かてい｝の電話機｛でんわき｝（色｛いろ｝が黒｛くろ｝かったので、一般に「黒電話｛くろでんわ｝」という）と違｛ちが｝う体系｛たいけい｝の無線｛むせん｝通信網｛つうしんもう｝で通話｛つうわ｝が接続｛せつぞく｝・交換｛こうかん｝されます。当然｛とうぜん｝、黒電話と番号[体系]{たいけい}も異｛こと｝なります。携帯電話は、携帯電話同士で通話｛つうわ｝できるのは当然｛とうぜん｝ですが、技術｛ぎじゅつ｝も進｛すす｝み、そのうち、体系の違う黒電話との通話も自由｛じゆう｝にできるようになりました。そのとき、「黒電話」は「市外局番」として運用｛うんよう｝されます。こうなると、すなわち、携帯電話と黒電話が同居｛どうきょ｝する環境｛かんきょう｝では、一般｛いっぱん｝の人の認識｛にんしき｝も、「市内番号」「市外局番」をそれほど意識｛いしき｝せずに、また、同じエリアコード内の[人]{ひと}同士でも、常｛つね｝に「市外局番」込｛こ｝みで電話番号を管理｛かんり｝し、他人｛たにん｝にも伝｛つた｝え合｛あ｝うようになりました。

この状況下｛じょうきょうか｝で電話番号を教｛おし｝えるときには、「市外局番」に当｛あ｝たる「横浜｛よこはま｝045」の「横浜」はそろそろ存在｛そんざい｝価値｛かち｝を失｛うしな｝いはじめておりますので、今｛いま｝では、大部分｛だいぶぶん｝の人が、「横浜」という念押｛ねんお｝しの言葉｛ことば｝を外｛はず｝して、「市外局番」込｛こ｝みの「045-123-4567」として伝｛つた｝えるということが一般的｛いっぱんてき｝になってきました。むろん、お[互]｛たが｝いが市内同士と分{わ}かっているときには、今でも、「123-4567」と市内番号だけをを伝える場合｛ばあい｝も併存｛へいぞん｝します。

この「併存する」状況｛じょうきょう｝がやっかいです。
もし、例｛れい｝のアナウンサーのように「電話番号は、045の」と言うと、「ぜろよんごおの」と発音｛はつおん｝するのでしょうが、聞｛き｝いている人は「えっ」となります。「045の」か「045?」と、「5」の後｛あと｝になにか聞こえたが「の」なのかそれとも何か別｛べつ｝の番号を言ったのか一瞬｛いっしゅん｝戸惑｛とまど｝います。実際｛じっさい｝に日本人が聞くとわかりますが、ここでは「045pause」の方が「045の」と発音｛はつおん｝するより聞き直｛なお｝しは少｛すく｝ないはずです。
それは、「市外局番」と「市内番号」とは本来｛ほんらい｝別物｛べつもの｝であったために、各々｛おのおの｝は分｛わ｝けて伝えるべきものであって、「～の中｛なか｝の/～の内｛うち｝の」という意味｛いみ｝合｛あ｝いでの「の」が登場｛とうじょう｝する場面｛ばめん｝ではないからです。市内番号の「123-4567」の中にある「–」は、本当｛ほんとう｝は「市内局番」と「加入者｛かにゅうしゃ｝番号」を区別｛くべつ｝するものです。しかし、この意味｛いみ｝を知｛し｝っている人はまずいないと思いますので、「123–4567」をどう発音するかは別｛べつ｝の話です。「1234567」と、７桁｛けた｝の数字｛すうじ｝をいっぺんに言う常識｛じょうしき｝[外]｛はず｝れはいないと思います。一般的には、中継｛なかつ｝ぎ的｛てき｝に、「–」のところで、「の」かpauseを入れます。これはどちらも使｛つか｝われているようです。市外局番と違｛ちが｝って、いつも聞きなれているリズムですので、「の」であっても、pauseであっても誤解｛ごかい｝が生｛しょう｝じにくいと思います。

なお、ǝʇɐןoɔoɥƆの答えで気｛き｝づいたのですが、比較的｛ひかくてき｝「の」の使用｛しよう｝を肯定的｛こうていてき｝に扱｛あつか｝っております。これは、たぶん、ǝʇɐןoɔoɥƆが関西｛かんさい｝の人だからだと思います。一本｛いっぽん｝調子｛ちょうし｝で発音される標準的｛ひょうじゅんてき｝な日本語の「ぜろよんごおの」と違｛ちが｝って、関西弁｛かんさいべん｝での「ぜろよんごおの」では「の」の前に独特｛どくとく｝のイントネーションと間｛ま｝（短｛みじか｝い pause のようなもの）があり、「の」が「–」の意味として使われていることが明瞭｛めいりょう｝に聞き分｛わ｝けられるように思います。

最後｛さいご｝になりますが、「045-123-4567」の正しい発音は、
「ぜろよんごお **pause** いちにいさん **pause** しいごおろくしち」
か、
「ぜろよんごお **pause** いちにいさん **の** しいごおろくしち」
です。
「ぜろよんごお **の** いちにいさん **の** しいごおろくしち」
は、ありません。子供｛こども｝っぽく、調子｛ちょうし｝も悪｛わる｝いですね。

Comment: Kewl, thanks, so no actual word is used in place of the hyphen then.

Comment: I feel like some times people will say の rather than pausing, do you think that's accurate?

Comment: @virmaior: Thank you for your information!  の is commonly used in reading an address (住所{じゅうしょ}) such as いち-の-に-の-さん for 東京都千代田区内幸町1-2-3, but as for telephone numbers, we use pauses for them.

Comment: Very helpful. I was getting that idea from reading addresses out loud.

Comment: I also thought this was the case as well. Some Japanese textbooks in English that I've read will say that for telephone numbers you'd read the hyphen as の, but I would trust a native first ;)

Comment: @ǝʇɐןoɔoɥƆ: 数字の読み方としてアナウンサーが正解とした電話番号の読み方がどうも違うように感じましたのでEDITしました。こんな考え方もあるのか程度でお読みください。