# 住所を読む時、なんで「の」って言うの？

Tags: word-choice, reading-comprehension

日本人じゃないけど日本語で書こうと思いました。

[この答](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/51931/22352)のコメント欄にこう書いてあります：

> の is commonly used in reading an address (住所{じゅうしょ}) such as いち-の-に-の-さん for 東京都千代田区内幸町1-2-3

確かにそうです。私も読む時にも、空で読むときにも、「の」と言います。日本人の皆さんが言うんだけど、それはなぜでしょうか？つまり、住所を読む時、ハイフンを「の」って読む理由はなんでしょうか？少し切って読んだら「の」と言わなくても大丈夫ですか？

Comment: Feel free to point out any Japanese errors (or edit them).  I learn best from making mistakes.

Comment: @edits I've also seen 「コメント欄」 or 「コメ欄」 used for comments section (but not コメント分)

Comment: ^「コメント欄」のほうがよかったですか？直しました～

Comment: @ǝʇɐןoɔoɥƆ ajsmartさんがそう言いたかった気がしましたけど「コメント」でも意味が通じますね

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「の」を入れる１つの理由としては、例えば、1-20-3 だったら、「いちのにじゅうのさん」って言わないと紛らわしいから（もし「いち にじゅう さん」って言ったら、 1-20-3 か 1-2-13 か 1-23 かわかりにくいから（もしかしたら 1-2-10-3 もあるかも？））じゃないかな？と思います。
<sub>(・・・けど、英語だとどうなるんでしょう？ もし "one twenty three" って言ったら 1-20-3 か 1-23 かわかりにくくなったりしませんか。）</sub>

> １丁目のなかの２０とか関係ないですか？

そうですね。この「の」は、「～丁目/番地**のなかの**～」「大阪**の**吹田市から来ました。」とか言うときの「～のなかの」「～にある」みたいな気持ちかもしれません。（[デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/171157/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%AE/)「の 1⃣１㋒ 所在。…にある。」）でも、電話番号なども「0120-333-906」を「ぜろいちにいぜろさんさんさん**の**きゅうれいろく」などと読んだりしますので、番地でも特に意味はなく使われているのかもしれません。

Comment: 英語なら「dash」ていうかな。例えば4-6-28を「four dash six dash two eight」と読むか「four dash six dash twenty-eight」と読む。人によるだけどね。

Comment: と言ったら１丁目のなかの２０とか関係ないですか？

Comment: そうそう、「いちのにじゅうのさん」って、正式には「１丁目２０番地３」という場合もあります。「～丁目」のない地域もあるけど。「１－２０番地３号」みたいなのとか（昔、大きな「１番地」だったところを、細かく分けた場合とか）。

Comment: ハイフンのとこに少し言い止めたらどうですかね？

Comment: ハイフンのところで、「いち、にじゅう、さん」ってしっかり切ったら、たぶんわかってもらえると思いますけど、「の」を入れたほうが聞き間違う可能性が低くなるから、やっぱり「の」を入れたくなるかもー＾＾

Answer (score 1):

> の is commonly used in reading an address (住所{じゅうしょ}) such as いち-の-に-の-さん for 東京都千代田区内幸町1-2-3

住所の最後の1-2-3は、正式（住民票）には「１丁目２番地３号」と記載されます。
しかし、1-2-3と書く方が簡単なのでほとんどの人が「丁目」「番地」「号」という漢字を使わず、dash/hyphenを使って書きます。
日本中の住所を調べますと、「１丁目２番地３号」のようにきちんとなっていないものも多数あります。現に、私の住所も最後は「◇◇◇番地の２」となっており、「丁目」「号」はありません。

日本人は年賀状を出しますが、筆で上手に字を書けない人が多いので、コンピュータを使って住所（宛名）を印刷するアプリ（application software）が発達しています。

そのための[市販されているアプリ](http://www.sourcenext.com/eshop/item/?code=208360&page=print)を紹介します。これを見るとＯＰが話題にしている「dash/hyphen」が実際に「の」「ノ」「～」「ー」で印刷できることが分かります。すなわち、日本人がこのような表記をしていることの証拠であり、「ー」を「の」「ノ」と発音している証拠でもあります。

この例では７丁目１０－５１、７丁目１０ノ５１、７丁目１０の５１ですが、他のアプリでは、また、私たちが普段使っている表記では７－１０－５１、７ノ１０ノ５１あるいは７の１０の５１のような場合もあります。それでも「ノ」や「の」より「ー」の方がずっと多いように思います。

次に、私の個人情報を通じて日本では住所を表示する該当の箇所に「の」が正式に使われていたことを証明します。**すなわち「ー」を便宜的に「の」と発音しているのではなく、実際に「の」が書類として使われているのです**。

1. 昭和５４年（１９７９年）の住民票

   - 本籍：〇〇市△△町◇丁目▽番地**の**１３
   - 住所：横浜市〇〇区△△町◇◇◇番地**の**２
2. 平成１８年（２００６年）の住民票

   - 本籍：<del>〇〇市△△町◇丁目▽番地**の**１３</del>
     　　　〇〇市△△町◇丁目▽番地１３
     　　平成１８年２月２０日　通知により本籍修正
   - 住所：横浜市〇〇区△△町◇◇◇番地**の**２
3. 平成１８年（２００６年）の戸籍抄本

   - 本籍：〇〇市△△町◇丁目▽番地１３
     戸籍改製　【改製日】平成１７年１２月１７日　【改製事由】平成６年法務省令第５１号附則第２条第１項による改製
     Revision of the Family Register 【Date of Revision】December 17,1999 【Reason of Renewal】In Accordance with the 1994 Ministry of Justice Ordinance No. 51, Supplementary modification made by the Article 2, Paragraph 1

これらの書類から判断できることは、私の戸籍も、住民票に記載された住所も、少なくとも１９７９年までは住所の中に正式に「の」が使われていました。そして、戸籍の方は法律により「の」がなくなりましたが、住民票の住所の方は**今でも**「の」があります。
但し私を含めてほとんどの人は「の」の代わりに「ー *dash/hyphen*」を用いて次のように書いて運用しており、「ー」の箇所は「の」と発音しております。
住民票に記載の住所：横浜市〇〇区△△町◇◇◇番地の２
日常使っている住所：横浜市〇〇区△△町◇◇◇番地ー２

「の」とは関係ありませんが戸籍の[翻訳例](http://terribletoadstool.publog.jp/archives/31262778.html)を紹介します。

[image]