# Are counters for houses used in addresses?

Tags: grammar, counters

I have a question about how to translate sentences like "the person from the eight", in the sense of "the person who lives in the house number 8". Is a counter preferred/needed in this situation? If it is, is the best counter 号? Is it droppable, so that we can safely say 八の人?

What motivated my question is the name of a Mexican TV show, which in English means "the boy from the 8". In the Japanese Wikipedia it is translated as 『[8のチャボ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A8%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BB%E3%83%81%E3%83%A3%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BB%E3%83%87%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BB%E3%82%AA%E3%83%81%E3%83%A7)』. However, this title sounds a bit unnatural to me (it seems like a counter is missing, but maybe the name translation is just ok because of the informal nature of the show).

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/51932/22352

Answer (score 1):

Probably the number 8 is more important key than the specific location of where チャボ　lives in the drama series. As the answers in the link, it is omittable. I don't know what's like "house number" is though, if it was room　in the apartment, 8号室 is specific. If it was the number of the apartment building itself, 8号棟　is common. I think the answerers in the link explained in detail.