# Is a の said after the first three digtis of 10 phone number?

Tags: particle-の, numbers

Lets say my phone number is (123)456-7890.

Should I pronounce it as:

> いちにさん　よんごろくの　ななはちきゅうゼロ

or

> いちにさんの　よんごろくの　ななはちきゅうゼロ

Comment: Reminds me of this thread.. Related, perhaps? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/51928/9831

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Native speakers use the 「の's」 most of the time.  Without using them, the phone number will not have the ***rhythm*** that we expect it to be read out with.  It just will not sound "right" without.

For keeping that rhythm, it is also important to know that we intentionally ***lengthen*** the syllables of 「に (2)」 and 「ご (5)」 to 「にー」 and 「ごー」, respectively, to produce the same "double-length" as the other digits that are originally double-length.

Thus, the number "(123)456-7890" is pronounced:

> 「いちにーさん**の**よんごーろく**の**ななはちきゅうぜろ」